# Modify indentation between label and content in LyX

Tags: lyx, lists

I have the following list, created with the 'Labeling' list style in LyX:
[image: Indented List]

LyX seems to automatically add a large indentation (e.g. between 'AB1' and 'Test') whenever pressing space or tab past the label.

LyX exports the following LaTeX code:

```
%% LyX 2.3.5-1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[oneside,english]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\newenvironment{lyxlist}[1]
    {\begin{list}{}
        {\settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}
         \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}
         \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}
         \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hfil}}}
    {\end{list}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{lyxlist}{00.00.0000}
\item [{AB1.}] Test
\begin{lyxlist}{00.00.0000}
\item [{a)}] Test
\end{lyxlist}
\item [{AC2.}] Test
\end{lyxlist}

\end{document}
```

How can I reduce the length of this indentation?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You might replace `{00.00.0000}` with `{AB1.}`, for instance. B.t.w., the default inputenc is `utf8` nowadays.